# Why doesn't this generate out-of-bounds access in C?

Tags: c, gcc, enums, c99

Playing around with some C code to do some comparisons between C99 and Rust, I've written the following,

```
typedef enum {
    NICKLE, DIME, QUARTER, DOLLAR,
} Denom;

static const int cents[] = {
    [NICKLE] = 5,
    [DIME] = 10,
    [QUARTER] = 25,
    [DOLLAR] = 100,
};

int main () {
    printf( "Result %d\n", cents[DIME] );
}
```

This works as expected, now I wanted to show an out of bounds access, and when I do

```
typedef enum {
    NICKLE, DIME, QUARTER, DOLLAR, ZOD = 20394
} Denom;
```

I was expecting

```
printf( "Result %d\n", cents[ZOD] );
```

To show access that was `cents + ZOD`. But it doesn't.

```
 mov eax, 0
 mov esi, eax
 lea rdi, str.Result__d        ; 0x5570bf1ed020 ; "Result %d\n"
 mov eax, 0
 call sym.imp.printf           ; int printf(const char *format)
```

Why is it setting `esi` to `0`, and why does this print

```
Result 0
```

There are also no errors with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`. Does GCC provide a flag governing this behavior? Does it know this to be out-of-bounds, and if so wouldn't it warn (or can it be made to warn) as well?

Comment: Seems the compiler can determine statically that it’s UB. It’s free to do whatever. (Look at the unconditional call with `-fsanitize=undefined`, for example.)

Comment: @Ry- that seemed likely I've updated the question to request if this is governed by a flag in gcc, and information on warning?

Comment: What maks you think that it does NOT cause out-of-bounds access?

Comment: @Yunnosch because I can see it clearing `rsi` which is the `0` in the output. And not actually accessing any memory. `rdi` is set to the format string. `rsi` is set to 0.

Comment: @Ry- that's really really cool. I never saw this before. With that flag it compiles different code and warns `test.c:16:30: runtime error: index 10049 out of bounds for type 'int [4]'`. Then it does the same thing before this. So that code actually generates a warning that I can see in runtime. But, GCC can't generate a warning in compile time? And it just quitely does the nice thing for me?

Comment: @JL2210 appreciate it =) I'm still mourning over not having gcc-docs in Debian https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/523080/3285

Comment: The online docs are better.

Comment: Strange that `extern const int cents[4];` generates warning but `static` doesn't. Would be nice if gcc would warn about static arrays, too.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I don’t know about gcc, but clang definitely can.

Comment: @Ry- Clang warns about everything and its friend. Just take `-Weverything -std=<c standard> -pedantic` and try to compile your project.

Comment: @JL2210: … yes? That’s how I always compile C.

Comment: @Ry- Oh. Well, uh, good job. Because my project just jams out a ton of warnings when I compile with those flags (but it is using double-underscores).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GCC can warn about this under specific circumstances (see @Acorn's answer).

There is a runtime undefined-behavior checker, [`-fsanitize=undefined`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#Instrumentation-Options), that should give an error if you do some types of undefined behavior, such as accessing past array bounds.

As this is undefined behavior, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants. That means it can set `esi` to zero, the hexadecimal representation of your password, or anything else.

Comment: That's just amazingly awkward that in order to catch an error caught in compile-time, that GCC can remedy in compile time, I have to enable a runtime undefined-behavior checker which has to generate different code than otherwise generated to notify me after the code path is hit.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yep.

Answer (score 1):

To add on the other answer, note that other compilers do warn about it with the source as given in the question.

For instance, Clang:

```
<source>:15:28: warning: array index 20394 is past the end of the array (which contains 4 elements) [-Warray-bounds]
    printf( "Result %d\n", cents[ZOD] );
                           ^     ~~~
<source>:7:1: note: array 'cents' declared here
static const int cents[] = {
^
```

As well as icc:

```
<source>(15): warning #175: subscript out of range
      printf( "Result %d\n", cents[ZOD] );
```

---

For GCC, you have `-Warray-bounds` which you get at `-Wall -O2`. In particular, you need `-ftree-vrp` (the optimization that allows to remove unneeded unnecessary range checks like array bound checks).

However, for some reason, GCC only gives the warning for a non-`const` non-`static` array. If you try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    NICKLE, DIME, QUARTER, DOLLAR, ZOD = 20394
} Denom;

int cents[] = {
    [NICKLE] = 5,
    [DIME] = 10,
    [QUARTER] = 25,
    [DOLLAR] = 100,
};

int main () {
    printf( "Result %d\n", cents[ZOD] );
}
```

you will see it warns about it:

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:15:5: warning: array subscript 20394 is above array bounds of 'int[4]' [-Warray-bounds]
   15 |     printf( "Result %d\n", cents[ZOD] );
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:7:5: note: while referencing 'cents'
    7 | int cents[] = {
      |     ^~~~~
```

I can get the warning to appear at least since GCC 4.4.7!

Comment: Thanks! I've incorporated this into my answer. If you aren't OK with that, I can rollback my edits.

Comment: Lucky. You have GCC 9 available. I'm stuck on 8.3.

Comment: @JL2210 Note that the warning appears even since GCC 4.4.7, no need for the latest GCC.

Comment: I know. Just the format of the warnings. I do have GCC 9 in my 32-bit Gentoo Prefix, but I hardly ever use it.

Comment: @JL2210 As for incorporating things into your answer, I don't think it is useful for readers (they have to read twice the same things) nor for writers (everyone would need to copy all the other answers into one). I prefer to reference other answers as I did (you can even give a link with the share button which contains your UID). By copying, you are also obsoleting my answer (because I wrote this answer complemented yours, which then it wouldn't anymore). At the moment, you are basically copying everything from this one into a single answer...

Comment: OK. Done. limit

Comment: @JL2210 Thanks! (what is limit?)

Comment: comment-length limit. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389069/ui-bug-when-comment-is-not-long-enough

Answer (score 0):

The C language definition does not mandate any kinds of bounds checking on array accesses - there is no requirement on either the compiler or the runtime environment to handle out-of-bounds accesses in any way.  The behavior is *undefined*.

Individual compilers *may* issue diagnostics if the out-of-bounds access can be detected during translation, and more are doing so over time (as other posters have said, gcc and clang do, but not by default).

If it can’t be detected until runtime - well, C doesn’t have any kind of structured exception handling mechanism, so there’s no good way to handle the issue even if it’s signaled by the runtime environment.